# ggplot2 colour appears in grey and not with colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

so i have this data
eight_gen_scatter:

```
pro = c("CONCOCT", "MetaBAT", "MaxBin", "MyCC")
MEGAHIT = c(3, 3, 3, 3)
RayMeta = c(3, 2, 1, 4)
SPAdes = c(3, 3, 2, 3)
Velvet = c(3, 3, 0, 2)
```

and i have the following code:

```
ggplot(eight_gen_scatter_melted,aes(x=variable, y=value, color=Programas)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge") +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="variable", breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                      labels=c("CONCOCT", "MaxBin", "MetaBAT", "MyCC")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 8))
```

[image]

But somehow the bars are with colour grey and just the border is with different colors, how do i fill up the bars with the colours.

I'll be very grateful if you could give some help.

Comment: You need to put `fill=Programas` inside `aes(..)` as well

Comment: Don't use `color = `, use `fill =`.

Comment: i tried that but the legend disappear so i tried the following aes(x=variable, y=value, color=Programas, fill=Programas)) butt the legend appears in grey, how do i solve that? @Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis code below works perfectly for me. I don't understand why did you add "scale_fill_discrete()"? Do you want to change the order of items in the legend?

The legend will be added automatically since you set "fill= Programas". So you don't need extra code.

`ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill= Programas)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")`